# Can Expandable Panels Be Created Using Native Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a requirement to be able to split a Lightning Component into two panels with the right panel expandable/collapsible. Similar in a way to sections but sections act in the opposite way, they expand/contract vertically instead of horizontally.
lightning component expandable section

Does anyone know if a horizontal equivalent exists which I can use for building panels similar'ish to sections but horizontally?

Thanks in advance for any tips on this.  I hope I've explained the above ok. I don't have any mock-ups unfortunately to help explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such thing, directly speaking. However, you can do this pretty easily with lightning:layout/layout:item:

```
<aura:attribute name="sideCollapsed" type="Boolean" default="true">
<lightning:layout>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="{!v.sideCollapsed?12:8}">
    Left Side Content
  </lightning:layoutItem>
  <lightning:layoutItem class="{!v.sideCollapsed?'slds-hide':''}" size="4">
    Right Side Content
  </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Toggling sideCollapsed will expand/collapse this side bar. You can experiment with various designs, such as adding padding or other elements within, etc.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, Thanks. Apologies I got totally sidetracked since I initially posted the question. The layoutItems work well.  One thing I've trying to figure out is how to replicate the detail & related tabs within a layoutItem.  I can use forceChatter for chatter functionalities but for standard detail & related sections, I know force:recordData can be used but this does not seem to appear in a layoutItem. For lightning:recordViewForm and lightning:recordEditForm do you know if there is a way to expose all fields from the page layout without individually specifying them?  Thanks.